# How do I add a separator in enquirer.js multiselect prompt for Yeoman generator?

Tags: javascript, npm, yeoman

I am creating a Yeoman generator using enquirer.js for my prompt and I can't figure out how to add a separator within a multi-select choice set.

I have tried using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/enquirer-separator

Here is my index.js file for the Yeoman generator:

```
var Generator = require('yeoman-generator');
const { prompt } = require('enquirer');
var Separator = require('enquirer-separator');

module.exports = class extends Generator {
  async prompting() {
    this.answers = await prompt([
      {
        type: 'multiselect',
        name: 'sizes',
        message: 'Sizes:',
        choices: [
          '160x600',
          '728x90',
          new Separator('- - - Uncommon - - -'),
          '180x150',
          '600x500'
        ]
      }
    ]);
  }
}
```

I would expect something like this when I run the generator:

```
Sizes:
- 160x600
- 728x90
- - - Uncommon - - -
- 180x150
- 600x500
```

But instead I just get this:

```
Sizes:
- 160x600
- 728x90
-
- 180x150
- 600x500
```

Any thoughts on how I would be able to get the expected prompt would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question was a bit buried in the documentation for enquirer: https://github.com/enquirer/enquirer#choice-properties The `enquirer-separator` package ended up being unnecessary. Here's how I got the separator I needed...

```
choices: [
   '160x600',
   '728x90',
   { message: '- - - Uncommon - - -', role: 'separator' },
   '180x150',
   '600x500'
]
```